# Failed to Display Image in Swift Package Manager XCAssets using UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, uiimage, matlab-spm

I'm currently working on Swift Package Manager project and I need to use images (`myImage`) I put in my custom XCAssets (`CoreUI.xcassets`). I have included my XCAssets in the SPM resources like this.

```
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MyCoreUI",
        dependencies: [],
        resources: [Resource.process("Resources/CoreUI.xcassets")]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "MyCoreUITests",
        dependencies: ["MyCoreUI"]),
]
```

I accessed my image like this:

```
UIImage(named: "dropdown_down", in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil)
```

But my image still failed to load without any warning. Could anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the resources property as Xcode should automatically recognize the xcassets file. Perhaps the problem is something else.

Comment: It still not recognise my image if I remove it

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue when I was working on my project. Solved the problem by using extensions. I saved all the XCAssets inside my CoreUI package. Now I can import CoreUI inside the main project and get the images. Add this code inside CoreUI package and add image names as static properties.

```
public extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(name: String) {
        self.init(named: name, in: .module, compatibleWith: nil)
    }

    static let home = UIImage(name: "Home")

}
```

Usage:

```
import CoreUI

yourImageView.image = UIImage.home
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue while accessing the image in the swift package manager. I fixed that issue by taking care of the following points.

1. As per [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/bundling-resources-with-a-swift-package) We don't need to process XIB, Storyboard, Assets Catalog, Core Data files .xcdatamodel and .lproj. So we don't need any special configuration on .package file.
2. I kept a root folder inside the Sources/MyPackage. Please check my directory structure as shown in the [image: attachment].
3. My Media.xcassets catalog have one image icon named `ic_patient`. I am able to access that with the following SwiftUI code:

   `Image("ic_patient", bundle: Bundle.module)`
4. It's working fine.